# jQuery CSS — force cursor to change on request (not only when mouse moves after request)?

Tags: jquery, css, cursor

Best way i can demonstrate is by example, if you go [here](http://tomdarracott.com/1/fabric/)
and move your mouse to the area right of the portfolio images, a S arrow appears.

When the user scrolls to the bottom of the page, i ask for the arrow to change to a N arrow.
It does this, but it only reflects the change once the user moves the mouse, which is not intuitive.

Is there a way i can force the cursor to change without the user having to move his mouse first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can, in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

In safari 5.1.1 all works fine... It changes automatically without moving the mouse when I'm about halfway the image of "creative review class of 2008"
Seems to be browser dependent then :s