# How to trigger custom cursor change on mousedown without mousemove event (jQuery)

Tags: html, jquery, css, mouse-cursor

### Trying to change the cursor

I am trying to make a draggable scrollable image and as such am trying to change the cursor over an image when a variable is set to zoom mode so I can have good usability. What I am finding is that the cursor only changes once I have clicked the ".page" and THEN moved the mouse not just as I click the page as it should. Here is some example code:

```
$(".page").on("mousedown", function (evt) {
    if(model.zoomMode){
        $('.page').css('cursor','url("img/hand_closed.gif"),auto');
    }       
}).on("mouseup", function (evt) {
    if(model.zoomMode){
        $('.page').css('cursor','url("img/hand_open.gif"),auto');
    }
});
```

### Another approach relying more on CSS

This seems to happen when I use classes to achieve the same effect as well. ie. zoom mode adds a class outside of the .page object and then the javascript is:

```
$(".page").on("mousedown", function (evt) {
    $('.page').addClass('mouseDown');
}).on("mouseup", function (evt) {
    $('.page').removeClass('mouseDown');
});
```

Then in the CSS:

```
.zoom .page:hover{
    cursor:url(../img/hand_open.gif),auto;
}

.zoom .page.mouseDown:hover{
    cursor:url(../img/hand_closed.gif),auto;
}
```

I am using chrome 18 to test. Anyone know a way to trigger the CSS cursor being applied without moving the mouse?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: Nope, sorry.

([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738767/jquery-css-force-cursor-to-change-on-request-not-only-when-mouse-moves-after))

Comment: if you can't do this what other options do I have? do I have to do something crazy like hide the cursor and create an image to show in its place and then poll for position information and reposition?

Comment: @Rudi: Maybe just for a second, until the user moves the mouse and the cursor change 'catches'. Then you could hide the image again. Other than that, I really have no idea. Edit: I assume you're avoiding jQuery UI and its juicy draggable function for a good reason?